# Multi-dimensional array, fill the matrix by numbers

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am completely stumped. I need to create a multi-dimensional array `n×n` and have it be filled in a particular way. I have been able to create the 2d array per `n×n` but have no idea how to fill it. Below I have included the task worded exactly as given to me:

> Given the number n, not greater than 100. Create the matrix of size `n×n` and fill it by the following rule. Numbers 0 should be stored on the primary diagonal. The two diagonals, adjacent to the primary one, should contain numbers 1. The next two diagonals - numbers 2, etc.
>
> Sample Input 1:
>
> ```
> 5
> ```
>
> Sample Output 1:
>
> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4
> 1 0 1 2 3
> 2 1 0 1 2
> 3 2 1 0 1
> 4 3 2 1 0
> ```

Here is my code so far. Any direction would be GREAT!!

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] array = new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach your problem:

I would use nested for loops, one to iterate over the rows, and one to iterate over the columns.  In my example, `i` is iterating over rows, and `j` is iterating over columns.  Now that I know I'm hitting each cell of the matrix once and only once, I just have to figure out a way to calculate the cell's value from `i` and `j`.  In this case, the cell's value is the column number minus the row number, or `j - i`, except there's no negatives, which can easily be solved with an absolute value (`Math.abs(int)`).  Below is how I would do it:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] array = new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { //iterate over rows
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { //iterate over columns
                array[i][j] = Math.abs(j - i); //calculate cell's value
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FillTheMatrixByTheNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
        int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = Math.abs(j - i);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String str = Arrays.toString(matrix[i]);
            str = str.replace("[", "")
                    .replace(",", "")
                    .replace("]", "");
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] array = new int[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                array[i][j] = Math.abs(j - i);
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract a column *index* from a row *index* or vice versa and take [`abs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)) value from a result. This way you get a cell value:

```java
int n = 5;

int[][] arr = IntStream.range(0, n)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, n)
                .map(j -> Math.abs(i - j))
                .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```